# Trim function in XPath 1.0?

Tags: xpath

Is there a trim function in XPath 1.0, that can be used like this:

```
.//a[trim(.) = @href)]
```

?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is [`normalize-space()`](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example6.html), which does a little more than trimming, but which may be fine for URLs.

Comment: Will the xpath `//button[normalize-space(text())='Brave Boy']` work for an element 
`<button type="button" class="addbutton pull-right ng-binding" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="modelPopup(dummy,'braveBoy','Unit Of Measure')" data-target="#popupEdit">&nbsp;&nbsp;Brave Boy</button>`

Comment: @Rameshwar Nonbreaking space is not directly supported, however you can translate those to normal spaces first so it will work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925537/xslt-normalize-non-breaking-whitespace-characters