# XSLT- normalize non-breaking whitespace characters

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a sample xml file like this,

```
<doc>
    <p>text1 text2  </p>
    <p>text1 text2     </p>
    <p>text1 text2   </p>
</doc>
```

this sample xml, first `<p>` has space whitespace character (`&#x0020;`), second `<p>` has tab whitespace whitespace character (`&#x9;`) and third `<p>` has space non-breaking whitespace character (`&#x00A0;`).

I need to remove the any white spaces appearing just before closing tag.

So, expected output should be,

```
<doc>
    <p>text1 text2</p>
    <p>text1 text2</p>
    <p>text1 text2</p>
</doc>
```

By using xslt normalize-space() I can remove unnecessary spaces and tab characters but not non-breaking whitespace characters.

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Any suggestions how can I normalize all white spaces including non-breaking white spaces in xslt?

Comment: if you have a list of the potential non-breaking charactes, you could do a `translate()` of those to a normal space before calling the `normalize-space`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' '))"/>
```

This will work in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 alike.

---

In XSLT 2.0, you could also use regex - for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[\t\p{Zs}]', '')"/>
```

will remove the horizontal tab character as well as any character in the Unicode `Space_Separator` category, which includes not only the space and non-breaking space characters but also other space characters. Documentation is hard to find, but I believe this is currently the complete list: (extracted from http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt):

```
&#x0020; SPACE
&#x00A0; NO-BREAK SPACE
&#x1680; OGHAM SPACE MARK
&#x2000; EN QUAD
&#x2001; EM QUAD
&#x2002; EN SPACE
&#x2003; EM SPACE
&#x2004; THREE-PER-EM SPACE
&#x2005; FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
&#x2006; SIX-PER-EM SPACE
&#x2007; FIGURE SPACE
&#x2008; PUNCTUATION SPACE
&#x2009; THIN SPACE
&#x200A; HAIR SPACE
&#x202F; NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
&#x205F; MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
&#x3000; IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

&#x10CB0; OLD HUNGARIAN CAPITAL LETTER EZS
&#x10CF0; OLD HUNGARIAN SMALL LETTER EZS
&#x16F36; MIAO LETTER ZSHA
&#x16F3C; MIAO LETTER ZSA
&#x16F3E; MIAO LETTER ZZSA
&#x16F41; MIAO LETTER ZZSYA
```

However, testing with Saxon 9.5 shows that the last 6 characters are not recognized: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSo

Comment: I'd never come across Unicode Categories before in Regex so reading https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html helped me understand `\p{Zs}` .